# Remove non ASCII chars from multiple files recursive

Tags: linux, command-line, find, batch-processing, tr

I have tons of files that include non ASCII characters and they are all over a complete file system. So I was looking for a batch solution but I run into one problem:

```
find . -name "*.yml" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file; do tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176' < "$file" > "$file"; done
```

This command should work fine, wouldn't there be the problem that tr -cd doesn't work if you use the same input and output name. Do you know any alternative or how I could solve this small issue?

GOT IT (no idea if that looks nice or crappy):

```
find . -name "*.yml" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file; do cp "$file" "${file}.temp" && tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176' < "${file}.temp" > "$file" && rm "${file}.temp"; done
```

Comment: ... use a temporary file (or variable)?

Comment: mhh, how would I do that and does that still work with one command line command or would it require a batch file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the file names you are processing, you may want to add `IFS=` and `-r` to the read command, see [Greg's BashFAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for details.

Regarding your question, use a temporary file as suggested by Carl or use the sponge command from [the moreutils package](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/). So either:

```
find . -name "*.yml" -print0 | 
while read -r -d '' file; do 
  tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176' < "$file" > "${file}.tmp" \
    && mv "${file}.tmp" "$file"
done
```

or:

```
find . -name "*.yml" -print0 | 
while read -r -d '' file; do 
  tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176' < "$file" | sponge "$file"
done
```

Comment: I think the syntax `tr ... < orig > tempfile && mv tempfile orig` is a little more reassuring - I mean the `&&` which only overwrites the original with the modified if successful.